# C/C++ CGI on Embedded device, POST, GET, LOGIN?

Tags: c++, c, cgi, webserver

I have here a small embedded device with uClinux.
There is a Boa web-server, that supports CGI scripts.
I need to make basic dynamic pages.

Requirements

- GET method for navigation
- POST method for forms
- LOGIN for authentication

I found this page http://www.cs.tut.fi/~jkorpela/forms/cgic.html
There is described how to implement GET and POST method.

But what about login and users?
Is possible to use login names and password from linux?
Do you have an example how to implement http authentication?

Or is better use this cgi c++ library?
http://www.gnu.org/software/cgicc/

I have no experience with that, thanks.

Comment: cgicc works well. Make sure you have the latest version to ensure you don't inherit buffer overflow vulnerabilities.

Answer (score 1):

Or you can try http://www.gnu.org/software/libmicrohttpd/ (never used, but there are references on google in uClinux-dist).

Comment: I use libmicrohttpd. It's basically an HTTP(S) server that you should be able to use in embedded devices.

Answer (score 1):

For authentication, you'll need to keep a "session state table" on the server. That is a static data structure, file, or db table that keeps track of currently-authenticated session ids, user ids they map to, and permissions. For security reasons, it's probably also a good idea to store the IP address and user agent in the state table (when Slashdot asks you whether your session never moves, moves within a subnet, or follows you everywhere, it's because they are invalidating any session that comes from outside your IP range unless you tell them specifically that it's okay).

Your CGI programs can then refer to the session state table to see if a given request is coming from a logged-in user, who that user is, and what permissions they have.

For security reasons, you should store the session id client-side in a cookie rather than in a GET string. Make sure that your session ids are random as best you can.

EDIT: your best bet for the session state table would either be MySQL/PostgreSQL if you're using it, or maybe IPC with a small C program you write specifically for that purpose, using either a built-in home-grown data structure or SQLite

Answer (score 0):

I'm also running CGI in C on an embedded device and using cgihtml open source library by Eugene Eric Kim.

So far it seems to work well for POST and GET methods. I have not used it for authentication.

http://www.eekim.com/software/cgihtml/index.html

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use either the URL parameters or cookies to store the authentication information.  Refer HTTP protocol for how to store cookies.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if your Linux distribution supports Perl. I have recently developed a CGI application using Perl and BOA web server for Angstrom Embedded Linux.

you can use perl CGI module for this.

Answer (score 0):

This shows digest authentication but you'd be best using a library to ensure it's handled correctly in all cases.  Notice how it uses GET although POST would work just as well.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digest_access_authentication

This sort of authentication has the browser pop up a little window for details rather than being an HTML form.  It isn't clear which sort of login mechanism you're after.

Answer (score 0):

try cherokee, it support various features, and embedded linux platform.

http://www.cherokee-project.com/

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cherokee_%28web_server%29

Answer (score 0):

I would use http://webtookit.eu

They provide a FastCGI deployment mode for your apps: http://www.webtoolkit.eu/wt/doc/reference/html/overview.html#fastcgi

Or a built in webserver (so you could possibly ditch the boa): http://www.webtoolkit.eu/wt/doc/reference/html/overview.html#wthttpd

And recently added authentication: http://www.webtoolkit.eu/wt/doc/reference/html/group__auth.html#details

Answer (score -1):

download squid cache server, it has a good secure and fast cgi with c.

Answer (score -2):

you can just try thttpd or LightHTTPd to serve this puropose , writing a custom C++ webserver is the best solution , if u dont have much functionalities to be looking at ... u can just start with looking at http://www.jbox.dk/downloads/webserver.c this implementation and extend it to support ur custom needs. If u are not planning for a dynamic web page hosting facilities in the webserver.

Regards,
Mike